# How do I use "Placeholder" in a T-SQL Query against a linked server connecting to a SAP-HANA?

Tags: t-sql, hana, linked-server, openquery

I need to extract data from a table view located in Hana into a MS-SQL table. From the HANA Team I am told I have to use a "placeholder" to prevent loading the changelog and the active table at the same time.

This is the query:

```
Declare @querytext nvarchar(1000)
Set @querytext ='
Insert into stagingtable
Select * from Openquery(LinkedServer,
''Select Field1, Field2, Field3 
From "SYSBI"."testdata.view/viewname"(''Placeholder''=(''$$Value1$$'',''00000''), ''Placeholder''=(''$$Value2$$'',''F'')); 
Where Field1 in (''ab'',''cd'',''ef''));''
'
EXEC(@querytext)
```

The Linked Server works (test connection works). Running this query within Hana (Or SAP) works.
However, when running the query in the SSMS with Openquery, I get a syntax error:

Incorrect syntax near 'placeholder'

I tried every variation of ", ' or '' or leaving it out altogether, but nothing seems to help. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax had some typos and there are still issues in putting everything into a string for the variable. However:

```
Insert into stagingtable
Select * from Openquery(LinkedServer,
'Select Field1, Field2, Field3 
From "SYSBI"."testdata.view/viewname"(''Placeholder''=(''$$Value1$$'',''00000''), 
''Placeholder''=(''$$Value2$$'',''F'')) 
Where Field1 in (''ab'',''cd'',''ef''));')
```

works as intended. 
I now "only" need to wrap the entire query into a string to put it into a variable.